# Finding association of attributes with node centrality/ degree value

Tags: regression, association-measure, social-network

I've run SNA and got the value of centrality of each node. I classified the centrality value into two group. Then based on this grouping, I would like to find the association of the attribute(gender, race, etc) with the grouping i've constructed. What statistical test that can I use? Can the classic logistic regression be use in this scenario?